What is correct for a professional context: genitive case or using "of"?
What is correct for a professional context: using the genitive case or using "of"? In our case it's an information text displayed to a user in a professional software mostly used by IT administrators.
Here is an example:

Please verify the recertification policy's category settings.

vs.

Please verify the category settings of the recertification policy.

Another, more general example would be:

The person's origin could not be verified.

vs.

The origin of the person could not be verified.


None of those sounds easy to understand, although in context it may be better. "Please verify the category settings for the recertification policy" sounds more natural, without knowing exactly what it means. From the question, it's not clear what the relationship is between the policy and the settings - I'd guess the settings describe how the policy is categorised, but maybe the policy determines what settings are used when other (unmentioned) things are categorised, or it could be something entirely different.

@StuartF I don't know if it's needed to answer the question, but here is more context: A recertification is divided into multiple categories of permissions to recertify. A recertification policy defines various options for when and how the recertification should happen. In a policy, various settings can be made for the available categories.

@StuartF But the question is more general. The sentence could be:
"The origin of the person could not be verified." vs. "The person's origin could not be verified."

@ManuelK: There is no single answer to this question: "The person's origin" is definitely better than "the origin of the person", while "the settings of the parameters" is definitely better than "the parameters' settings". And there are cases when both options are equally acceptable.

Deciding purely between genitive apostrophe-s and "of" might be done based on length (longer prefers "of"), but there are other options: alternative prepositions like "in" or "for", and attributive nouns ("recertification policy category settings") which would depend on the logical relationship between the words. "Do neither" in itself is not a very useful answer.

The choice often depends on whether you're using single-word nouns or more complex noun phrases. "person's origin" is simple and understandable, but it's easy to lose track of the grouping in "recertification policy's category settings"

I'd go with periphrastic and Saxon genitive respectively here.

Is your question about those two specific examples, or about the general rules?

@alphabet The first example brought up the question in the first place, but it's more about the general rules.
